# How to split output after executing SQL Server stored procedure into rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm now writing a script in SQL so that I can execute the output in Powershell to generate report. The code goes like this.

```
declare @from datetime, @to datetime
select @from=GETDATE(), @to=GETDATE()+1

SELECT ---$shape500.text='+'"'+'Assignation de Barrières-' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@from)+','+DATENAME(MONTH,@from)+' '+DATENAME(DAY,@from)+','+DATENAME(YEAR,@from)+'"'
+'$shape'+cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+
'=$page.DrawRectangle'+'('+CAST(X1 as varchar)+','+CAST(Y1 as varchar)+','+CAST(X2 as varchar)+','+CAST(Y2 as varchar)+')'
+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.'+'linestyle="Gantt"'
+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.'+'textstyle="Gantt"'+case when left(arrival, 2)='AC' THEN 'Red' ELSE '' END+ CASE WHEN LEFT(Departure, 2)='AC' THEN 'Red' ELSE '' END +' '+' '
---+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.FillStyle="Gantt"'+CASE WHEN CHARINDEX()
+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.Text="'+case when LEN(arrival)<>0 THEN Arrival ELSE '###' END +'/'+ [ACType Iata]+'/'+ CASE WHEN LEN(Departure)<>0 THEN Departure ELSE '###' END +'"'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'=$page.DrawLine('+cast(X1 -0.5 as varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+','+cast(X1 +0.5 as varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+ ')'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.Text="'+CONVERT(char(5), [Allocation Start Datetime], 108)+'"'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.TextStyle="Times"'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.LineStyle="Times"'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'=$page.DrawLine('+cast(X2 -0.1 as varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+','+cast(X1 +0.1 as varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+ ')'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.Text="'+CONVERT(char(5), [Allocation End Datetime], 108)+'"'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.TextStyle="Times"'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.LineStyle="Times"'
+'$shape'+ cast(300+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'=$page.DrawLine('+cast(X1 as varchar)+','+cast(Y2 as varchar)+','

FROM GanttReports(default,default)
```

`GanttReport` is a stored procedure. The output will generate everything in one big string like

> $shape1=$page.DrawRectangle(42.666660,6.78,58.083330,7.025)$shape1.linestyle="Gantt"$shape1.textstyle="Gantt"  $shape1.Text="QK8718/DH1/QK8749"$shape101=$page.DrawLine(42.166660,6.75,43.166660,6.75)$shape101.Text="16:21"$shape101.TextStyle="Times"$shape101.LineStyle="Times"$shape201=$page.DrawLine(57.983330,6.75,42.766660,6.75)$shape201.Text="17:30"$shape201.TextStyle="Times"$shape201.LineStyle="Times"$shape301=$page.DrawLine(42.666660,7.025)

However what I want is in separate rows. You can say split it using '$shape' as deliminator?

I know I can create a split function as I searched in the forum, however, not sure how to use it in this case. I'm quite new in SQL Server, will appreciate if someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the result from GanttReports in a variable of varchar type

like

Decalre @str varchar(max)

**Select @str** = '$shape'+cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)
FROM GanttReports(default,default)

**Then use the split function to return a table set.
To use a below split function I used dbo.seq table which is populated with nums from 1 to 1000
Its used to return the ur result in rows.**

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetNums') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@n AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
  SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n <= @n;

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.seq (nbr bigint)
go

Insert into seq
Select *
from dbo.GetNums(1001)

**create function [dbo].[fn_Delimitter]** (@string nvarchar(MAX), @delimiter varchar(100)) 
returns table 
as
return (
select str = rtrim(ltrim(substring(@delimiter + @string + @delimiter, nbr + len(@delimiter), charindex(@delimiter, @delimiter + @string + @delimiter, nbr + len(@delimiter)) - nbr - len(@delimiter))))
                 from    seq
                 where   nbr <= len(@delimiter + @string + @delimiter) - len(@delimiter)
                 and     substring (@delimiter + @string + @delimiter, nbr, len(@delimiter)) = @delimiter)
GO

Declare @str varchar(max)

Select @str = '$shape1=$page.DrawRectangle(42.666660,6.78,58.083330,7.025)$shape1.linestyle="Gantt"$shape1.textstyle="Gantt" $shape1.Text="QK8718/DH1/QK8749"$shape101=$page.DrawLine(42.166660,6.75,43.166660,6.75)$shape101.Text="16:21"$shape101.TextStyle="Times"$shape101.LineStyle="Times"$shape201=$page.DrawLine(57.983330,6.75,42.766660,6.75)$shape201.Text="17:30"$shape201.TextStyle="Times"$shape201.LineStyle="Times"$shape301=$page.DrawLine(42.666660,7.025)'

**Select * 
from dbo.fn_Delimitter**

go